# Choregraphe: How can I turn on NAO's Brain LEDs through qichat?

Tags: nao-robot, choregraphe

Using a "Dialog"-box (so a .top file too), how can i turn NAO's brain leds on? I know that you can call an output like "$turnledson=1" and connect it to "Set Leds"-box and turn the leds on that way, but what about a command that can activate them without the need of another box from choregraphe? Something like "^start(animations/LEDs/BrainLedsOn)", if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct LED commands in QiChat.

However, if in your app `myapp` you [create a new behavior](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/nao-naoqi-2-1/naoqi-developer-guide/programming/choregraphe-user-guide/choregraphe-tutorials/your#choregraphe-howto-create-a-behavior) called `brain/anim1` (with a box in it!), and you make sure [it is exposed (checked in the project properties)](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/nao-naoqi-2-1/naoqi-developer-guide/programming/choregraphe-user-guide/main-panels/project-content#project-properties-), you can use `^start(myapp/brain/anim1)` to start your Choregraphe behavior within your QiChat code.

But as you can see, you need to use a Choregraphe box somewhere in the end.

Comment: Thats actually smart. Thanks mate